# What solver should I use for an ordinary non-linear differential equation of a first order and second degree with 3 variables on matlab?

Tags: matlab, math, differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

In a fluid dynamics problem I am asked to plot the relative of a water drop falling in air with respect to time.
The relative velocity is a component of the velocity in the x,y,and z directions, I tried searching for a possible solution for this here in matlab documentation but all the examples are for a less number of variables.
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/differential-equations.html?searchHighlight=differential%20equations&s_tid=doc_srchtitle

Comment: This is just the problem of free fall of a (relatively) solid body with air friction? Or is the deformation of the drop and its possible splitting, evaporation etc. also under consideration?

Comment: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask this question.  But check their terms and conditions before re-posting it.

Comment: If you can do it for 1 variable what is then the problem of doing it for more? I mean the equations are exactly the same.